# Como obter uma resposta Blob com AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu estava lendo na documentação do MDN que é possível obter uma resposta `Blob` através do ajax, conforme o código abaixo:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var blob = oReq.response;
  // ...
};

oReq.send()
```

Eu gostei da ideia e gostaria de saber se é possível obter uma resposta `Blob` também através do `$http.get` do Angular.

Eu sei que por padrão, o AngularJs é configurado para enviar  e receber `application/json`, mas gostaria de saber se tem algum lugar para configurar recebimento de `Blob`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o `application/json` seja relativo, qualquer coisa pode ser blob, mesmo sendo até texto puro, já que o Blob é uma API do JavaScript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Serve para representar dados "raw", conforme a doc o `$http.get` usa `XmlHttpRequest`, então é possível setar o valor `'blob'` de `responseType` como mostrado em:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Os detalhes de suporte do `responseType` podem ser encontrados em:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

Não entendo muito de AngularJS, mas conforme o que li na documentação seria algo como:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', { 'responseType': 'blob' }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Pelo que li o `blob` em `XMLHttpRequest` tem um bom suporte, o único lugar que não vai funcionar são navegadores como IE9 ou mais antigos.

No AngularJS é possível configurar outras coisas:

- `method`
- `url`
- `params`
- `data`
- `headers`
- `eventHandlers`
- `uploadEventHandlers`
- `xsrfHeaderName`
- `xsrfCookieName`
- `transformRequest`
- `transformResponse`
- `paramSerializer`
- `cache`
- `timeout`
- `withCredentials`
- `responseType`

No entanto isto já é outro caso.

Comment: Não precisa do `'config'`, na verdade. Dá pra setar `{ responseType: 'blob' }` direto

Comment: @WallaceMaxters entendi, não imaginava, acho que posso ter lido errado :) ... vou ajustar.